# How do I put together numbers in java?

Tags: java, numbers

For some reason when I run the following code the program prints out "JDN4" or "JDN16" when at all times I want it to be printing "JDN" followed by three numbers ranging from 0-9; for example, "JDN123" or "JDN045" or "JDN206". What is wrong with the code?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Document2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String initials = "JDN";
        int randomNumbers;
        Random generator = new Random();
        int randomNumber1 = generator.nextInt(9);
        int randomNumber2 = generator.nextInt(9);
        int randomNumber3 = generator.nextInt(9);
        randomNumbers = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
        String userName = initials + randomNumbers;
        System.out.println("Your username is " + userName +  ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: You are adding the numbers as numbers.. If you "add" them to an empty string ("") they will get concatenated as strings instead

Comment: OK, I won't add an answer, all the ones given below are fine (and are the same) - But have you considered that you may get twice the same username? That smells like a potential bug to me, you should check for unicity!

Comment: + adds numbers and concats strings. Don't use it to "concat" numbers you will only get 1 or 2 digit numbers then in this case ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is `randomNumbers` is declared as an `int`, so when you use the `+` on the other ints, it will sum the integers rather than concatenate them.

So, if we were to use your approach, we'd need a string:

```
String userName = initials + randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
```

---

But it would be a lot easier just to generate a number from 0-999 and pad it with zeroes:

```
int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(1000);
String usernName = initials + String.format("%03d", randomNumber);
```

---

*Something else worth noting is that* `Random.nextInt(n)` *generates a random number between 0 (inclusive) and `n` (exclusive), so you probably should be doing* `.nextInt(10)` *if you want a number between 0 and 9.*

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have three numbers:

```
int randomNumber1 = 3;
int randomNumber2 = 4;
int randomNumber3 = 5;
int randomNumbers = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
```

Do you expect `randomNumbers` to be 345? Or do you expect it to be 12?

Now try this:

```
String randomNumbers = "" + randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
```

What do you get this time?

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
String userName=String.format("%s%d%d%d",initials,randomNumber1,randomNumber2,randomNumber3);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
randomNumbers = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
```

You're adding the numbers, not concatenating them.

Suggested solution: use only 1 random number with

```
generator.nextInt(1000);
```

Or, you can go like:

```
String userName = initials + randomNumer1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
```

But I'm nearly sure you'll get 2 or even 3 times the same number, so you should use the first approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the numbers here.

```
randomNumbers = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3;
```

If you want to achieve what you are looking for using this same method you could do.

```
randomNumbers = randomNumber1 + (randomNumber2 * 10) + (randomNumber3 * 100);
```

Comment: Actually, I'd say the other way around, since numbers are formatted as big-endian: `randomNumber1 * 100 + randomNumber2 * 10 + randomNumber3`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Since we are talking about random numbers, why should endianness matter?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: It doesn't matter from a practical point of view, but it does make the result display the same as `"" + randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3` (as opposed to `"" + randomNumber3 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber1`), which may help the OP understand this approach better.

Comment: this also has the additional "difficulty" that you must care about  leading zeros

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that the `+` operator does an addition, and not a concatenation when used on `int` variables.

Use

```
String randomNumbers = Integer.toString(randomNumber1) + Integer.toString(randomNumber2) + Integer.toString(randomNumber3);
```

to convert the numbers into strings and concatenate them.

Comment: Obviously if you were to do this you'd have to declare `randomNumbers` to be a `String`

Comment: You're right. I missed this in the OP's code. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding three digits, that would at most give you 27. You want to concatenate the string representation of those digits.

That said, why don't you simply generate a random number between 0 and 999?

Comment: Generating random number from 0 to 999 might be a little bit of a nuisance simply because it would mean that numbers 0 - 99 would have 1 or 2 extra zeros to add to the string. That said, I think that it wouldn't be too hard to do it anyway. Probably not the best approach though.